# Chrome extension permission issue

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension that makes an ajax request for Netflix RSS feeds.  Example feeds look like this:

http://www.netflix.com/Top25RSS?gid=307
http://www.netflix.com/Top25RSS?gid=2444

Everything works great until netflix begins serving from www2 in the evening (I'm assuming due to heavier traffic).  When that happens, my permissions no longer match in my manifest.json file and I begin having cross domain issues.  Here is the permissions section from my manifest.json:

"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "http://*.netflix.com/*",
    "http://69.53.236.17/*"
  ]

I've tried adding a wildcard in place of the www to account for it (as Google shows in their [docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/xhr.html)), but it doesn't work.  Does anyone know what I can do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `"http://*.netflix.com/"` as the permission. The wildcard will match all subdomains of netflix.com.

Comment: I tried but it still doesn't work (I meant to include that one in my example above as it was what I was referring to, but I guess I deleted it somehow).

Comment: Is it switching to ssl? You would have to add a second permission if that is the case.

Comment: I don't believe so.  I readded "http://*.netflix.com/" and now it works.  I guess I had a typo before.  Thanks for the help!